# Azure API Management set-body "liquid" template fails with "Stream was not readable"

Tags: liquid, azure-api-management

I am working on a change to a working API Management endpoint. I needed to send the request body to a backend service for some authentication / validation before calling the backend service.

I used `context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true)` to get a copy of the original request body.

However, now my `<set-body template="liquid">` template fails with the message "Stream was not readable".

The template is responsible for converting the request body, which is XML, to a JSON format, which the backend accepts.

It was my understanding that using `preserveContent: true` will allow the liquid template to access the body but it doesn't appear to be the case.

What other options do I have? Can I store the body on a variable and pass it to liquid explicitly? Is it better to just revert to LINQ to XML, where I at least got control of the data?

Edit:

I have since then abandoned using this feature of liquid for a more manual, but reliable approach.

Comment: That does not seem right, couldn't reproduce it right now. Could you show whole policy you're using, and possible trace of a failing request? Just make sure to remove all secrets that are there.

Answer (score 0):

Via the following inbound API Management policies, using a Liquid template, it gets **converted into a valid SOAP request**.

```
<inbound>
   <base />

   <!--Change for GET to POST-->
   <set-method>POST</set-method>

   <!--Set mandatory SOAPAction HTTP header-->
   <set-header name="SOAPAction" exists-action="override">
      <value>GetOrderDetails</value>
   </set-header>

   <!--Create SOAP Request via liquid template-->
   <set-body template="liquid">
      <GetOrderDetails xmlns="tvh.blogs">
         <OrderId>{{context.Request.MatchedParameters["orderId"]}}</OrderId>
      </GetOrderDetails>
   </set-body>

</inbound>
```

The `xml-to-json` policy is not sufficient for this scenario, because some fields require renaming, the order needs to be controlled and dates need to be formatted.

```
<outbound>
   <base />

   <!--Create JSON Response via liquid template-->
   <set-body template="liquid">
   {
   "orderId" : "{{body.GetOrderDetailsResponse.OrderId}}",
   }
   </set-body>

   <!--Set correct content type-->
   <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
      <value>application/json</value>
   </set-header>
</outbound>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2018/08/13/my-experiences-on-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't see how it relates to the `Stream was not readable` error as a result of calling `context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true)`.

Comment: The code you provide to get the original request body is right and could not reproduce your error without your policy. So I provide another option that you could try. If you want to solve the error please give your whole policy. Thanks.